# why is MongoDb wrapping ObjectId(' ') to a string

Tags: mongodb, api, loopback, loopback4, objectid

Mongodb keeps wrapping a string value with ObjectId(' ') in the database.

when I make a POST request with my endpoint, I get a 200 response and I see the correct value for my **creatorID** property that is of type string.

it looks like this: [image]

but in MongoDB it is saved like this:
[image]

**why is it doing that? and can I turn this option off?**

my other Id property (on level 1) is the unique id of the object and it gets automatically generated. Both are of type string.

any help would be appreciated!

Comment: In your schema, you can specify the type as `string` when inserting into the db. Default behaviour for IDs is to store as ObjectID. You can override that in your schema code in your api. Checkout `valueOf()` and `toString()` methods for usage.

Comment: Would it be possible to provide the source code for the Models?

Answer (score 0):

It can make its own unique definition automatically, you can turn this feature off.
[for more detail](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/)

example :

```
 var subSchema = mongoose.Schema({
         createId: string;
        // subschema content..
    }, { _id : false });
```

or

```
  @Prop({_id:false})
  SubSchema: subschemaArray;
```